# NativeScript + Angular: Code Sharing Project

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-codesharing, nativescript-schematics

I followed the Nativescript steps for creating a new code sharing project [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project) and I would like to use sass. I tried both for ones that have the NatievScript theme as well as the one that does not:

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics no-theme-project --shared --no-theme
```

or

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics sass-no-theme-project --shared --style=scss --no-theme
```

For this Post I chose ***No Theme***. When it finishes creating a new project the folder is as shown:

[image]

Inside `Desktop/TestProjects/sass-no-theme-project` I install the node modules:

```
npm install
```

When running `ng serve --o` the application builds and loads up as expected in the browser. For NativeScript mobile however for Android (have not tested iOS yet) the application crashes with an error. I have tried both `tns run android` as well as using the NativeScript SideKick to build however they end up with the same results. I have also tried local and cloud builds.

### Device Used:

Physical Samsung A5: Not emulator

### Error On Mobile Device In Logs:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Application entry point file not found. Please specify the file in package.json otherwise make sure the file index.js or bootstrap.js exists.\nIf using typescript make sure your entry point file is transpiled to javascript.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6065)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Application entry point file not found. Please specify the file in package.json otherwise make sure the file index.js or bootstrap.js exists.\nIf using typescript make sure your entry point file is transpiled to javascript.
    at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:311)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:544)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6062)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./", relative to: app//
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
    at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:309)
    ... 12 more
```

### Logs In Command Line and NativeScript Client

```
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) [./main.ns.ts] 1.22 KiB {bundle} [built]
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) [./package.json] 123 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI)     + 403 hidden modules
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) ERROR in Patterns must be a string or an array of strings
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI)  Webpack compilation complete.
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI)  Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI)  # tns build android
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) ### Description
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) clean-webpack-plugin: /mnt/storage/builds/_/1bfec9e7b462a1843535f909d892c70d2010e1cf/5.0.0/5.0.0/no-sass-project/platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/app/**/* has been removed.
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) Executing webpack failed with exit code 2.
[18-11-10 17:43:53.724] (CLI) bc_GgX4lpDXQFHYT4ydmJ
[18-11-10 17:43:56.917] (CLI) Unable to apply changes on device: 5210ffc964ca44f3. Error is: Build failed..
[18-11-10 17:43:56.920] Error detected during LiveSync on 5210ffc964ca44f3 for C:\Users\userName\Desktop\no-sass-project. Error: Build failed.
[18-11-10 17:43:56.925] (CLI) Executing after-watch hook from C:\Users\userName\Desktop\no-sass-project\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-sass.js
[18-11-10 17:43:56.925] (CLI) Executing after-watch hook from C:\Users\userName\Desktop\no-sass-project\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
[18-11-10 17:43:56.925] (CLI) Executing after-watch hook from C:\Users\userName\Desktop\no-sass-project\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-10 17:43:56.925] (CLI) Stopping webpack watch
```

With Nativescript and Angular creating a blank new project for me I would assume it is suppose to be a HelloWorld project that works in Web, iOS, and Android right out of the gate.

### UPDATE

I tried following the troubleshoot guide [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/troubleshooting) such as reinstalling `JDK 8` and that however the problem persists. I got it to run once, it failed and after about 4-10 minutes it rebuilt and was working. Since then I can not get it to work a second time. This leads to me believe there maybe a configuration issues somewhere such as the `tsconfig` `json` files. Taken a look in them and they seem to be fine.

Comment: I have seen his happening when I don't inject `moduleId` in component decorator - (`moduleId: module.id`)

Comment: I have the same problem. If I find something I'll let you know

Comment: Thanks, as will I. This should work out of the box for Android and iOS so seems strange

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this? I am not sure if this is an issue and the nativescript team is aware or not.

Comment: Not sure if anyone else has had success yet. I am starting to think the nativescript team put it up without testing it. Followed it about 10 times now and still cannot find build

Comment: New update it seems to be working now with tns run android --bundle. It failed at first and about 3 minutes later it closed and re-opened working. Not sure if the file was not converted to as a starting point so it starts with a crash and ends up rebuilding when its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it may be difficult for the nativescript team as the packages it relies on keep changing rapidly. This is the package.json setup I used thanks to @NickIliev from the nativescript team, @skopekreep, and good old debugging. If you use this setup you should be fine.

Just be wary updating the packages in the future and test before committing your package.json.

As well as the main packages I would suggest you be careful updating and ensure you test:

`typescript`
`@types/jasmine`
`nativescript-dev-webpack`
`tns-core-modules`

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "nativescript": {
  "id": "org.nativescript.myproject",
    "tns-android": {
    "version": "5.0.0"
   }
},
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "android": "tns run android --bundle",
  "ios": "tns run ios --bundle"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/common": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/http": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.1.0",
  "@angular/router": "~6.1.0",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "nativescript-angular": "~6.1.0",
  "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
  "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
  "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.0",
  "@angular/cli": "^6.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
  "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
  "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~1.7.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.6.0",
  "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
  "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.17.0",
  "protractor": "~5.3.0",
  "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1",
  "typescript": "^3.1.6"
}
}
```

**Steps:**

1. Install latest version of Node JS
2. Install latest version of NPM
3. npm i -g @angular/cli
4. npm i -g @nativescript/schematics
5. Go into the folder and replace the package.json, ensure to change name and id to your projects name
6. npm install
7. tns run android --bundle

Comment: I have issues System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6  after using your package json

Comment: Have you made other changes before that? If you follow this guide for a code sharing project: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project and then use my package.json before you use npm install it should be fine.

Comment: I added some steps for you to follow. Ensure you have xcode or android installed with SDKs. Or have your ios or Android device connected.

Answer (score 0):

When you build code-sharing projects you should use the `--bundle` flag.
So your command should be:

`tns run android --bundle` or `tns run ios --bundle`

If you keep forgetting the `--bundle` flag, then you could use the scripts provided in *package.json* and run:
`npm run android` or `npm run ios`

Additionally, if your project uses TypeScript 2.7, then you might need to update it to 2.8

As a side note: you don't need `moduleId` in code-sharing projects, as webpack is taking care of this for you.

Comment: Hello Seba Wita, I do run the command tns run android --bundle. Maybe something is wrong on my pc. I will try again from a new pc from scratch and let you know.

Comment: Also I did try before using the Nativescript Sidekick origionally. Not sure if that would cause an issue.

Comment: We are going to release a new version of the @nativescript/schematics tomorrow, which should include an update for angular 7.
It should also resolve an issue with the TypeScript version.

Comment: You believe is may be why the build is crashing? I did create a github ticket here if it helps: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6552. Thanks for the sturdy replies